# Can't click anywhere when ErrorProvider is set

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have the following code:

```
private void myTextBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
        if (some condition)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            errorProvider.SetError(myTextBox, "Error occurred");
            return;
        }
    this.errorProvider.SetError(this.myTextBox, null);
}
```

And the following `Button_click` code to trigger all `Validating` events:

```
private void saveData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.ValidateChildren())
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

It did validate correctly. However, I can't seem to click anywhere besides `myTextBox` when I click that texbox without changing its invalid value. Can I disable that "locking to your error until you change it" feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the behaviour of your controls, whether they are allowed to lose focus while having invalid data or not.

On your form you can set the following property:

```
this.AutoValidate = AutoValidate.EnableAllowFocusChange;
```

For details and other ways of getting a similar effect, please have a look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.autovalidate?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_AutoValidate_EnableAllowFocusChange)